# git log commit count for every file

Tags: git

I'm trying to get the following from `git log`:
1- number of commits for every file in the repo (between two dates)
2- number of contributors who edited every file (between two dates)
3- number of distinct contributors who edited every file (between two dates)

I've tried playing with `git log` but I wasn't that successful. I also tried searching for scripts but with no luck. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(when using the usual Unix tools)

Number of commits for given file in the repo:

```
git log --oneline ${filename} | wc -l
```

Number of contributors for given file:

```
git log --pretty=format:%ae ${filename} | sort -u | wc -l
```

Number of contributors for given file between two dates:

```
git log --since=${date1} --until=${date2} --pretty=format:%ae ${filename} \
    | sort -u | wc -l
```

Now, to iterate this for every file in current repo, you'd do something along the lines of:

```
find | grep -v '^\./\.git' | while read filename
do
    echo "${filename} has $(git log --oneline ${filename} | wc -l) commits"
done
```

Comment: I've tried the first two commands with couple of files both returned the same numbers for different files! weird! As for the file names I've tried it using src/.../filename and using folder/.../filename as I'm already under src/